# Why do my Visual Studio 2010 applications require installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I create an application with Visual Studio 2010 and then try to run the exe, it requires that I install it. I'm trying to create a very simple program that doesn't require installation. An example of this would me something like procmon.exe. You can run procmon without any installation required.

Also, is it possible to create the exe without requiring a certificate?

Comment: Such programs are created as a Win32 console application in C++, not in vb.net. You should find a way to disable installation or certificate features for your VB application.

Comment: I never encountered this problem myself. Check your project setting under Signing and see if everything is turned off (shpuld be). This is for the certificate part. For executing just the file, should be as easy as double-clicking it. Look into ILMerge if you are using added dll-files as this will help you merge everything into a single file (there exist some ILMerge GUIs to help you out).

Comment: Just in case you mix this point up - the target computer will always need to have the .net framework installed, in that version that you use for your application.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a Windows Form application to a Win32 application from within Visual Studio?